# Error in installing mysqlclient on mac with python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, macos

I am facing below issue in python while installing mysqlclient:

```
 Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/joy/workspace/my_project/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qj7p_p1n2d38w4ysr50qvgfc0000gp/T/pip- 
 install-tfjwlop6/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; 
 __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/rz/qj7p_p1n2d38w4ysr50qvgfc0000gp/T/pip-install- 
 tfjwlop6/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open). 
 (__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
 __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 
/private/var/folders/rz/qj7p_p1n2d38w4ysr50qvgfc0000gp/T/pip-wheel-s9xhvytf
   cwd: /private/var/folders/rz/qj7p_p1n2d38w4ysr50qvgfc0000gp/T/pip-install- 
tfjwlop6/mysqlclient/
Complete output (30 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g - 
fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -
D__version__=1.3.13 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/include/mysql -
I/Users/joy/workspace/my_project/venv/include -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o 
build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-
3.6/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o 
build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
```

In this regard, I have gone though a several posts here, but not getting any clue regarding how to fix this on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got the gcc compiler installed. It comes with "Command line tools voor XCode" if I'm correct. So all you have to do is go to the app store and download XCode.

You can check if its installed by running `gcc -v` in the terminal.

Comment: @ensjeflensje, gcc is already installed:

 $gcc -v

Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin